# WooCommerce: disable flickity dragging on specific product pages

Tags: woocommerce, flickity

I have setup a custom script on the first product image that uses the dragging events. But now, when I drag - the slider starts functioning. I have figured out how to disable the dragging after the page has loaded (through firebug). But how can I disable right after it's been setup by woocommerce?

I tried this:

```
flickityInterval = setInterval('disableGalleryDrag()', 1000);

function disableGalleryDrag(){
        //disable draggable for gallery
        $carousel = jQuery(".product-gallery-slider").flickity();
        var flkty = $carousel.data('flickity');

        flkty.options.draggable = false;
        flkty.updateDraggable();

        clearInterval(flickityInterval);

}
```

But it works only partially for some reason. A little dragging does not initiate the slider dragging, but if you do a bigger slide it does.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just needed to handle the errors.

```
flickityInterval = setInterval('disableGalleryDrag()', 1000);
function disableGalleryDrag(){
    try {
        //disable draggable for gallery
        $carousel = jQuery(".product-gallery-slider").flickity();
        var flkty = $carousel.data('flickity');

        flkty.options.draggable = false;
        flkty.updateDraggable();

        clearInterval(flickityInterval);
    }
    catch(err) {

    }

}
```